# Namespace prefix getting changed from request to response

Tags: wsdl, websphere, xml-namespaces, soapui

I developed one service using websphere application server and Rational application developer(RAD) . I am using SOAP UI to unit test my service. The service is well deployed and getting the accurate results but the problem is in the namespace prefixes.prefixes of response i am getting is different from the prefixes of request namespaces. i.e. if request having namespaces defined as common, domain etc..i am getting response having namespaces as a,b,c ..

the request is as goes here...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:tic="http://www.trrt.com/pos/TicketRemark_v1"  xmlns:dom="http://www.tport.com/pos//Domain" xmlns:com="http://www.tralport.com/pos//Common">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tic:RetrrksRequest  Version="1" >
         <dom:TicketDocument TicketNbr="6000001"/>
      </tic:RetrrksRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the response is...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <c:RetrrksResponse Version="1" TimeStamp="2012-08-23T14:15:59.000" xmlns:a="http://www.trrt.com/pos/viewtrip/schema/CommonTypes_v1" xmlns:b="http://www.trport.com/pos/viewtrip/schema/DomainTypes_v1" xmlns:c="http://www.travt.com/pos/viewtrip/schema/TicketRemarksServices_v1">
     <a:Success/>
     <b:TicketDocument TicketDocumentNbr="6000000000001" TotalDocQuantity="7"/>
     <b:BookiID CreateDateTime="2012-08-12T12:40:00.000" PurgeDate="2013-06-20" ID="ABCDEF">
     </b:BookiID>
     <b:FeeRemarks>
        <b:Remark Type="3000">remark text</b:Remark>
     </b:FeeRemarks>
  </c:RetrirksResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: My question is how to change the namespace prefix at response??

Comment: as pglezen put it in his answer, you should not depend on the XML namespace prefix which can be anything

Comment: Okay that is correct . Thank u for spending precious timings...

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem.  The namespace prefix may be arbitrary, so long as it references the correct namespace.  One should not depend on the particular choice of a namespace prefix.  Any code that does rely on a choice of prefix will likely suffer interoperability problems.